# aggregate query in mongodb in php returning null

Tags: php, mongodb

I ran this command in rockmongo tools- command
and its returning correct values

```
{ 
    aggregate : "twits",                                
    pipeline : [
         {$group : {_id : "$by", num_tutorial : {$sum : 1}}}
    ]                
}
```

and then I tried to extract the values from it using this

```
 define("__COLLECTION_TWITS__","twits");
```

in `/var/www/html/TradeTwits/require/config/DBConfig.inc.php`

```
$collectionName=__COLLECTION_TWITS__;
$db = $this->connection("mo");
$col = $db->$collectionName;

return $col->aggregate(['$group'=> array('_id' => '$by','num_tutorial' => array($sum => 1))]);
```

in `/var/www/html/TradeTwits/app/models/BaseModel.php`

The above code should be returning all records grouped by usernames,
but when in php ,it is not working fine.

Am using phalcon framework using PECL class library to access mongodb
and rockmongo as GUI for accessing mongodb collection

It is returning correct values for `find()` `count()` etc.Should I use another library for aggregate or pipeline?

Comment: `$sum` should have simple quotes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aggregate should be an array of arrays. I think here, you missed an array.

The documentation says:

```
$ops = array(
    array(
        '$project' => array(
            "author" => 1,
            "tags"   => 1,
        )
    ),
    array('$unwind' => '$tags'),
    array(
        '$group' => array(
            "_id" => array("tags" => '$tags'),
            "authors" => array('$addToSet' => '$author'),
        ),
    ),
);
$results = $c->aggregate($ops);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! :) A little bug was ruining it :)